# Pass configured log4js instance to class

Tags: javascript, log4js-node

I am using `"log4js": "^4.3.1"`. I am having a main file that configures the class and the `logger` instance.

```
const {
    StartLogger
} = require('./StartLogger')
const log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure('./config/log4js-config.json');


async function main() {
    const logger = log4js.getLogger();
    logger.level = 'info';

    const startLogger = new StartLogger(logger)
    startLogger.hello("hello")
}

main()
```

My class looks like the following:

```
const log4js = require('log4js');

class StartLogger {

    constructor(log) {
        logger = log
    }

    hello(msg) {
        this.logger.info("Your Message: " + msg);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    StartLogger
};
```

However, I get - rightfully - the following exception:

> ReferenceError: logger is not defined

Any suggestion how to pass the configured instance to the class?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 0):

here, you need to define logger at `this` level

```
    constructor(log) {
        this.logger = log
    }
```